# Modify Strongloop/Loopback built-in input arguments in API Explorer

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to know if it is possible to change the default input parameters of builtin methods like 'create', but only for input (not using the [hidden](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Hiddenproperties) property) and only for this method. In this case, I want to suppress the "balance" parameter. In other words, in the pointed location, my api explorer needs to show the following:

```
{
  "userId": "string"
}
```

[image]

I have managed change custom remote methods, like so:

[image]
Using the following code:

```
module.exports = function(User) {
    User.makeDeposit = function(data, callback){
        //Method logic
    };
    User.remoteMethod(
        'makeDeposit',
        {
            http: {path: '/makedeposit', verb: 'post'},
            returns: {type: User, default:'User', root: true},
            accepts: {arg: 'req', type: 'object', default: prettyJSON(depositSchema), http: {source: 'body'}}
        }
    );
};

// Returns a pretty printed json
function prettyJSON(str){
    return JSON.stringify(str, null, '  ');
}

// Input Schemas - Only used for API Explorer
var depositSchema = {};
depositSchema.userId = "hash123";
depositSchema.amount = 11.37;
```

But I cannot replicate for built-in methods. Any help?

Comment: I think the only way is redefining builtin remote methods